# Source not Found Error in Eclipse BlackBerry App

Tags: java, eclipse, mobile, blackberry, java-me

I'm new to BlackBerry application development.  I have one silly error while during `HttpConnection` in `httpcon.getResponseCode()` method giving source not found error.

Please, can any one figure out this error?

Here is my method:

```
        net.rim.device.api.io.transport.ConnectionFactory cf = new   net.rim.device.api.io.transport.ConnectionFactory();
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) cf.getConnection(url).getConnection();

        httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept_Language", "en-US");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                Integer.toString(postData.length));
        os = httpConn.openOutputStream();
        os.write(("LoginID=yahoo@sol.com&Password=yah123")
                .getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        try {
            responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            //check if it's eof, if yes retrieve code again
            if (-1 != ex1.getMessage().indexOf("EOF")) {
                try {
                    responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                } catch (IOException ex2) {
                    System.out.println(ex2.getMessage());
                    // handle exception
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(ex1.getMessage());
                // handle exception
            }
        }
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        if (status == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            InputStream input = httpConn.openInputStream();

            byte[] bytes = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(input);

            StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer(new String(bytes));
            raw.insert(0, "bytes received]\n");
            raw.insert(0, bytes.length);
            raw.insert(0, '[');

            url = raw.toString();

            input.close();
        } else {
            url = "response code = " + status;
        }
        httpConn.close();
    } catch (IOCancelledException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return "";
    } catch (IOException e) {

        return "";
    }

    return "";
}
```

**Update:** I am not trying to step into `getResponseCode()`.  Eclipse is stopping execution at that point, and showing the **Source Not Found** error.

Comment: what are you trying to do?  is this a **compile** error, or are you trying to *step into* a method in the debugger?

Comment: @Nate yes we are step into method that time only we are getting Run Time Error.Error is displayed When `Getresponsecode()` is called.

Comment: @Nate i have found my mistake.When calling `HttpConnection. getResponseCode()` in that URL String we have to add `deviceside=true` then only `getresponsecode()` will be called without throwing any http exceptions. For Example:        `httpClient ht = new httpClient();
String str = ht.getHttpClientResponse("https://www.google.co.in;deviceside=true",post);`

Comment: Thanks for the update!  Note that with BlackBerry, you don't **always** want `deviceside=true` in your connection strings.  It depends on whether you're running on a device or a simulator, and what kind of network's available.

Comment: By the way, you can post your comment *"... I have found my mistake ..."* as an answer, and **accept** your own answer.  That way, people know that you don't still need help with this.

Comment: Thanks @Nate. Have look into answer i have mentioned your  "... Thanks for the update! ..." comment also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my mistake.When calling `HttpConnection. getResponseCode()` in that URL String we have to add deviceside=true then only getresponsecode() will be called without throwing any http exceptions.

For Example: 
`httpClient ht = new httpClient(); 
String str = ht.getHttpClientResponse("https://www.google.co.in;deviceside=true",post);`

Note:
(From @Nate Comment)
we don't always want `deviceside=true` in your connection strings. It depends on whether you're running on a device or a simulator, and what kind of network's available.

Answer (score 2):

> @Nate yes we are step into method that time only we are getting Run Time Error.Error is displayed When Getresponsecode() is called

Does your eclipse *error* look like this?

[image]

`getResponseCode()` is a method in the `HttpConnection` class.  This is RIM's code, not yours.  You normally shouldn't need to step **into** that code.  Just step **over** that line while debugging.  The only thing you should want to see is the *result* of that method, not what happens inside.

Even if `net_rim_api.jar` is included in your project, that simply gives you the binary version of RIM's classes, including `HttpConnection`.  It doesn't provide the Java **source** code for that class.  In order to step **into** a method, you would need to have the source code, too.

Comment: Yes its `Data gram Protocol (connection base).receive (data gram) line 538` in header.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your comment.  Is Eclipse telling you that it cannot find the source to `DatagramProtocol`?  Is it doing this when you try to **step into** the `getResponseCode()` method, or is the program stopping its execution at that line?  Make sure you understand what I'm asking here (if not, let me know).  If the debugger is stopping on its own, then an exception is being thrown by your app.  Eclipse is probably setup to automatically break on unhandled exceptions.  But, I need to know if you are actually **trying** to **step into** the RIM library code.

Comment: also, you call `getResponseCode()` many times.  can you tell us which call to `getResponseCode()` is giving you these problems?  thanks.

Comment: Its stopping the Entire execution. I'm not trying to step into into RIM lib.

Comment: you probably didn't see my last comment, but if you could answer that question, that would be helpful.  if you are **not** trying to step into the RIM library, then your networking code is throwing an exception.  try putting a breakpoint in all of your exception handlers.  use the Eclipse debugger continue button to continue until you hit one of those breakpoints, and then tell us **which** exception is being thrown.  that is the key to solving your problem.

Comment: I have removed those repetations of calling `getResponseCode()`.Currently i have called only one time in this method.But still its displaying the Exception.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21948/discussion-between-r-1-and-nate)